# Does Crud Repository has saveAll method that works?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use CRUDRepository for my development project. I have seen in many posts that CRUD Repository do support saveAll method which allows to save a list of object in the database. But when I am using it, It is giving me an error that saveAll property is not found 
Here is the detailed error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BinaryPartCRUDRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract java.util.List xxx.xxx.xx.xxxx.repository.BinaryPartCRUDRepository.saveAll(java.util.List)! No property saveAll found for type BinaryPart!
```

Here is my code.

```
       public interface BinaryPartCRUDRepository extends CrudRepository<BinaryPart, Long> {
       BinaryPart save(BinaryPart binaryPart);
       List<BinaryPart> saveAll(List<BinaryPart> binaryParts);
    }
```

The save Function is working. But saveAll is not.
I have also tried to use the Persistence manager to do the batch save. But having null object while doing JUnit Testing. So I am preferring to stay with CRUD Repository. Appreciate any kind of suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`saveAll` already there in `CrudRepository`, so no need to specify your own method for save all in repository interface.

**remove this part:**

```
List<BinaryPart> saveAll(List<BinaryPart> binaryParts);
```

and in your service class , directly call `saveAll method. Remember this method using iterable as param and return value.

Comment: I don't see `CrudRepository::saveAll` in Spring Boot 1, but `save(Iterable)` presented.

Answer (score -1):

The `saveAll` method has the following signature:

```
    <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);
```

You define an **additional** method with the same name, but a different signature. Spring Data does not know how to create an implementation for that and throws the exception.

Just change your interface to:

```
public interface BinaryPartCRUDRepository extends CrudRepository<BinaryPart, Long> {}
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: no, it isn't. safeeul has additional methods declared in the interface.